# Cannot resolve symbol 'PlaceBuilder'

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I get the error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'PlaceBuilder'

when it is used in my PlaceAutocompleteAdapter. If this that it is due to the fact that `com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer` is deprecated.

If this is the reason, how can I update my code?

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutoCompleteClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            hideSoftKeyboard();

            final String placeId = mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter.getItem(i).getPlaceId();

            PendingResult<PlaceBuilder> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCllback);

        }
    };

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCllback = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
            if(!places.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: Place query did not complete successfully: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                places.release();
                return;
            }
            final Place place = places.get(0);

            try{
                mPlace = new PlaceInfo();
                mPlace.setName(place.getName().toString());
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "onResult: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            if (mPlace!=null){
                moveCamera(mPlace.getLatlng(), DEFAULT_ZOOM, mPlace.getName());
            }

            places.release();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

PlaceBuffer is indeed deprecated. Please migrate to the new Places SDK for Android following Google's guide https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Hope this helps!